# Dealing with null values in F#

Tags: .net, f#, return-value, null

As you can see by the mass of questions I'm asking, I'm really getting deeper and deeper into F#  :)

Another doubt approaches my learning path: null values. How to handle them considering that it is necessary because of the tight integration between the .NET framework and F# (or any other language in the framework)?

To keep it simple, here's a slice of code:

```
let myfunc alist =
   try
      List.find (fun x -> true) alist
   with
      | :? KeyNotFoundException as ex -> (* should return null *)
```

How can I return a null in a function?
The `null` keyword is useless, unless recognized (not the same for `nil`).
And, generally speaking, what's the best practice when handling null returned values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the question is.  If you complete your example:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

let myfunc alist =
   try
      List.find (fun x -> true) alist
   with
      | :? KeyNotFoundException as ex -> null
```

you'll find that it compiles just fine, and the inferred type `myfunc : 'a list -> 'a when 'a : null` indicates that the type stored in the list that you pass in must have `null` as a proper value.  F# is perfectly capable of dealing with null values when using types defined in C#, VB.NET, etc.

However, when you're not interoperating with code written in another .NET language, the typical approach would be to return an `'a option` to indicate that a value may or may not be present.  Then, your example would become:

```
let myfunc alist =
   try
      List.find (fun x -> true) alist
      |> Some
   with
      | :? KeyNotFoundException as ex -> None
```

which will work on lists containing any type (even ones which don't have null as a proper value).  Of course, in this case you could just use `List.tryFind (fun _ -> true)` instead.

Comment: I agree, but I think `List.tryFind` deserves more prominent mention. Requiring the .NET framework to generate a call stack and throw an exception every time it doesn't find what you're looking for is not the way to good performance. `let myfunc = List.tryFind (fun _ -> true)` is the way to go.